# Authentication Fail with MongoDB Compass Community

Tags: mongodb

I've just created a new MongoDB account and I'm now trying to connect the free cluster I created via MongoDB Compass Community application but I'm getting a 'Authentication Fail' error being displayed.

This is what I've checked so far:

1. From my MongoDB Clusters section when I clicked on the Connect (…) button which then gives you various options. From there, I selected 'Connect with MongoDB Compass' and copied the connection string.
2. This was detected as expected by the Compass and the information was filled automatically in all the relevant fields and I also filled the password by copy/pasting it into the relevant field. 100% sure it is correct.
3. I checked that the username used was indeed set up as an admin and it is.
4. I checked my Authentication database was correct and it is.
5. I've checked that my public IP was added to the whitelist and it is. The only thing I've noticed is that when I added my public IP address, it added a /32 at the end. Is that the port?

But I'm not quite sure what else to test for to resolve this problem.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I eventually found out what the problem was after speaking to someone from MongoDB support Team!

Everything was done correctly except for one thing. I was being impatient after changing my Cluster User's password. It can take up to 2 minutes for the system to be updated and therefore to allow Compass to access it.

Once I waited a couple of minutes, I was able to login as expected in Compass.

I still can't quite believe I wasted so much time on such a simple issue but the main thing is that it is resolved.

I did send them some feedback as a lot of things could have been done a lot better:

1. Highlight it better in their documentation i.e. red??
2. Make the "warning" message displayed on the webpage after updating the user details more obvious. It was right in my face and never spotted it appear or disappear as once I'd update the user detail on the website, I'd swap immediately to Compass to try to login. By the time, I'd be done, well over 2 minutes would elapsed and the message would be long gone, so not very useful the way it is currently done.
3. Instead of just saying: 'Authentication Fail', which is correct, the message could read differently when it knows the user is being updated i.e. 'Authentication Fail - Please try again in a few minutes as we're updating this user's details'... Something like this anyway.

So, remember to be patient when changing your user's details in MongoDB and if you are, then yes, you will have a database up and running in the cloud in 5 minutes or less! :)