# MongoDB compass not connecting

Tags: string, mongodb, express, compass, atlas

I copied the connection string from atlas and input it in my mongodb compass. But it's showing bad Auth: Authentication failed when I tried to connect. What could be happening and how do I fix the error?

Comment: Have you reviewed [Compass authentication troubleshooting](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/compass/current/troubleshooting/connection-errors/#authentication-failed) and whitelisted your IP address?

Comment: dublicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51120265/authentication-fail-with-mongodb-compass-community